# bash script to insert ip address into property file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a property file with an entry such as this:

```
some.url={ipaddress}/blah
```

I want to substitute the {ipaddress} with the ip of machine its running on.

I found this command:

```
ipconfig getifaddr en0
```

which outputs the ip.

I also found sed is useful for this sort of thing but I can't quite put it all together.

```
sed -i '' 's/{ipaddress}/192.168.0.1/g' test.properties
```

Where the hard-coded ip address 192.168.0.1 needs to be substituted for the machine's one.

Can anyone help?

Comment: use double quotes instead of single quotes for variable expansion.

Comment: i need more information such as how to capture the output of the ipconfig command to a variable to then use in the sed command.

Comment: Seems like you need to learn the basics of shell scripting, then. Capturing the output of a command is one of the first things you'll learn.

Comment: The `g` at the end of this sed expression will cause ***all*** instances of "{ipaddress}" to be replaced.  Make sure that is what you want.  Or do you just want to replace the instance on lines that begin with "some.url="?

Comment: all occurrences is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the result of the `ipconfig` command in a variable like this:

```
ip=$(ipconfig getifaddr en0)
```

Then interpolate it into your sed command by surrounding the expression with double-quotes:

```
sed -i "" "s/{ipaddress}/$ip/g" test.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cat file
some.url=10.10.10.5/blah
```

```
awk -F"=|/" '{print $1 "=" ip "/" $3}' ip=$(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{print $NF;exit}') file
some.url=192.168.1.30/blah
```

`ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{print $NF;exit}'` is one of the best way I have found to get correct IP. It works even on VPS servers and on servers with multiple IP